Angular Interceptor - retrieve Graphql query or mutation name
Good morning everyone,
I would need your help to retrieve the query or mutation name within the interceptor which is working fine.
import { HttpContextToken, HttpInterceptorFn } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment'


export const REFRESHER_TOKEN_INTERCEPTOR = new HttpContextToken(() => false)
export const authInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {

  //By dafault, the interceptor will try to pass the JWT token but for the refresherToken we must pass the refresher token instead
  const jwtToken = getJwtToken(req.context.get(REFRESHER_TOKEN_INTERCEPTOR));

  if (jwtToken) {
    var cloned = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`
      }
    })
    return next(cloned)
  }
  return next(req);
};

The reason why I'm asking, it's in case of refresher token mechanism, I would like to send another token
Find a way to retrieve the query or mutation name from within the interceptor

in case you are looking for a solution, see below how to simply get it:
const operationName = req.body.operationName

